# How do I add a dynamic text file to a very simple heroku app?

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications, storage

I have a *very* simple heroku app that is basically running one python script every ten minutes or so 24/7. The script uses a text file to store a really simple queue of information (no sensitive info) that gets updated every time it runs.

I have heroku set to deploy the app via Github, but it seems like way too much work to make it programmatically commit, push, and redeploy the entire thing just to update the queue in the text file. How can I attach this file to Heroku in a way that can let it be updated easily? I've been playing around with the free database add-ons but those also seem overcomplicated (in the sense that I've got no clue how to use them).

I'm also totally open to accusations that I'm making mountains out of molehills when I could easily be using some other easier platform to freely run this script 24/7 with the queue file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point I'm sure that nobody cares, but this answer is for you, [future troubleshooter](https://xkcd.com/979/).

It turns out that the Heroku script works fine with a txt file queue. Once the queue included in the Heroku deployment, the script will pull from the queue and even update it, giving the correct behavior. all you have to do is put the queue in with the github repo and open/change the file with the python files as you normally would.

The confusing thing is that this *does not* change the files in Github. It leaves the (github repo copy) queue as the same text file it was when it was originally pushed. This means that pulling and pushing the repo is a little confusing because the stored queue gets out of date very fast.

Thanks for the question, me, I'm happy to help.